# How can i load external json file in highcharts for making bar chart

Tags: highcharts

I have tried to load JSON file from external link in Highcharts. I am doing this code by referring the example given in Highcharts website,but when I loading the web page,it doesn't show any bar chart and when opening console there is no error found.I have following type of json data.

```
 [
    {
    "Country_Name": "MYANMAR",
    "value": [
        143
    ]
},
{
    "Country_Name": "MONGOLIA",
    "value": [
        46
    ]
},
{
    "Country_Name": "ZIMBABWE",
    "value": [
        1
    ]
},
{
    "Country_Name": "Bahrain",
    "value": [
        1
    ]
  }
  ]




  $(document).ready(function() {

      var options = {
        chart: {
         renderTo: 'container',
          type: 'spline'
      },
       series: [{}]
   };  

       $.getJSON('try.json', function(data) {
        options.series[0].data = data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });

    });
```

Comment: And when you open in Chrome -> Console -> Network, what Status do you have for your AJAX call? I would try to remove `;` at the end of JSON file.

Comment: when i remove ; from the JSON file, then running code in Google Chrome,it's console says Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function try1.html:22
(anonymous function) try1.html:22
m.Callbacks.j jquery.min.js:2
m.Callbacks.k.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
x jquery.min.js:4
m.ajaxTransport.send.b

Comment: Show your full code. Not only parts.

Comment: Do you really have JSON inside of JS file?

Comment: Your json is also incorrect, because data should contain "y" field, instaed of "value", and should be object, not array. Correct form: data:[1,2,3] or data:[{y:1},{y:2},{y:3}]